# KineticJS image zoom

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I'm working on a project where I have kineticJS regular polygons fillpatterned with images that I would like to zoom out on hover.  Currently I'm using

```
    this.setFillPatternScale(zoom)
```

in order to zoom out, but this simply changes the background image size rather abruptly.  Is there any way to make this process more of an animation (like using css and transition ease) or simply more smooth than an abrupt switch.  I thought about using incremental scaling and redrawing the shape but that seemed pretty intensive and it is already pretty slow to run as is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use a Kinetic.Tween to scale your fillPattern:**

```
tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
  node:image, 
  fillPatternScaleX:(1+scaleFactor*2),
  fillPatternScaleY:(1+scaleFactor*2),
  fillPatternOffsetX:0,
  fillPatternOffsetY:0,
  duration: .25,
  onFinish:function(){ this.reverse(); }
});
tween.play();
```

[image][image]

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/NHZAV/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var tween;
    var scaleFactor=.25;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){

        var image=new Kinetic.Rect({
            x:50,
            y:50,
            width:img.width*(1+scaleFactor*2),
            height:img.height*(1+scaleFactor*2),
            stroke:"red",
            strokeWidth:3,
            fillPatternImage:img,
            fillPatternRepeat:"no-repeat",
            fillPatternOffsetX:-img.width*scaleFactor,
            fillPatternOffsetY:-img.height*scaleFactor,
        });
        layer.add(image);
        layer.draw();

        tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
          node:image, 
          fillPatternScaleX:(1+scaleFactor*2),
          fillPatternScaleY:(1+scaleFactor*2),
          fillPatternOffsetX:0,
          fillPatternOffsetY:0,
          duration: .25,
          onFinish:function(){ this.reverse(); }
        });
        tween.play();

    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/ship.png";

    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        tween.play();
    });

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="myButton">Again</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>ml>
```